# What is the R equivalent of PadLeft() and PadRight() in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, r

In .NET, I can use [`string.PadLeft()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfw3aeeb%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [`string.PadRight()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to pad a string with spaces on the left/right.

```
var myString = "test";
Console.WriteLine(myString.PadLeft(10)); //prints "      test"
Console.WriteLine(myString.PadLeft(2)); //prints "test"
Console.WriteLine(myString.PadLeft(10, '.')); //prints "......test"    
Console.WriteLine(myString.PadRight(10, '.')); //prints "test......"
```

What is the equivalent in R?

Comment: Example/explanation of exactly what `.PadLeft()` and `.PadRight()` do would have stopped me voting this down. Feel free to edit.

Comment: Do you want/need the answer to allow user-settable pad characters (as in your example), or is space-padding sufficient?

Comment: @Ben Bolker I'm happy with space padding. I didn't even know that .PadRight can pad with a specific character, but I can imagine this might be useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass the length in as a parameter:

```
PadLeft <- function(s, x) {
  require(stringr)
  sprintf("%*s", x+str_length(s), s)
}

PadRight <- function(s, x) {
  require(stringr)
  sprintf("%*s", -str_length(s)-x, s)
}

PadLeft("hello", 3)
## [1] "   hello"
PadRight("hello", 3)
## [1] "hello   "
```

Comment: Nice, really nice. I'm quite familiar with C#, so it's great to know that I can make my R code look a little more familiar.

Comment: Why not use `nchar` here? to avoid NA cases?

Answer (score 7):

Use `sprintf`, which is built into R:

```
# Equivalent to .PadLeft.
sprintf("%7s", "hello") 
[1] "  hello"

# Equivalent to .PadRight.
sprintf("%-7s", "hello") 
[1] "hello  "
```

Note that, like .NET, the number specified is the total width that we want to fit our text into.

Answer (score 5):

Use `str_pad` from `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
str_pad("hello", 10)
str_pad("hello", 10, "right")
str_pad("hello", 10, "both")
```

Comment: Ah, I see it now. I did look through http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/stringr.pdf but missed this call.